# Arquivo não encontrado no PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

Instalei um *script* e está funcionando corretamente, porém no site há uma área restrita e, ao fazer o login, o site cai e dá o seguinte erro:

> An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file:
>   ../../public_html/themes/private/template.php

Segue o código da pagina em questão:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Base Private Class - used for all private pages
 */
class Private_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('currencys');

        // must be logged in
        if ( ! $this->user)
        {
            if (current_url() != base_url())
            {
                // store requested URL to session - will load once logged in
                $data = array('redirect' => current_url());
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }

            redirect('login');
        }

        // prepare theme name
        $this->settings->theme = strtolower($this->config->item('private_theme'));

        // set up global header data
        $this
            ->add_css_theme( "{$this->settings->theme}.css" )
            ->add_js_theme( "{$this->settings->theme}_i18n.js", TRUE );

        // declare main template
        $this->template = "../../{$this->settings->root_folder}/themes/{$this->settings->theme}/template.php";
    }

}
```

Comment: Está utilizando CodeIgniter? Se sim, seria interessante adicionar a tag. O erro está porque o arquivo de *template* não existe. Já se certificou se ele existe no diretório especificado?

Comment: O teu problema é bem provavel que seja este `../../` que existe no começo do diretório que está sendo atribuido a `$this->template`. Verifique onde exatamente está este arquivo `template.php` e corrija este diretório para que aponte para o arquivo.

Comment: Alterei esse final para:    // declare main template
        $this->template = "public_html/themes/private/template.php"; que é onde exatamente ta o arquivo template.php

Comment: mas ainda assim permanece o mesmo erro

Comment: Paulo, o erro agora ficou An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: public_html/themes/private/template.php